# Bridging WiFi and Lan in Windows 10

Tags: networking

When I make a Bridge Connection of an 8 MB/s WiFi and 8 MB/s USB Tethered LAN together, I only get 8 MB/s. I've tried this before and haven't faced this problem.

I make the Bridge Connection by selecting them and right click and create a new Bridge Connection.

Thanks

Comment: To understand what you want, are you expecting 16mbps?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: What OS? (Windows I guess). What are you actually trying to accomplish (before you decided a bridge was what you wanted) and then tell us the research you've done regarding this.

Comment: I've done the exact thing before and could achieve aggregated connection.

Answer (score 1):

Bridging is for connecting two networks together end to end, not in parallel. It allows the computer to sit in the middle of a connection to share that connection further down another connection.

You've just created an internet loop.

It sounds like what you want is an aggregated connection, but even that isn't really viable. Two connections running in parallel require very specialized hardware in order for the speeds to be added together for any given connection.

A more normal setup, simpler, and something supported by more normal network hardware, is that multiple connections give you redundancy, not faster speeds.

Comment: But I've done this before and could get aggregated speed. Is there any way to achieve this without specialized hardware?