# Windows 11 using two internet connections at one: Wifi + USB-iPhone, to sum up speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, iphone, tethering

is that possible?, how make it work?

I explain,
I have a not so fast connection on my school-residence (wired Ethernet with avg 40mb down, 15 mb up) and infinite data on my iPhone (USB-tethering with avg 60mb down and 20 mb up) when at dorm

I have connected both to my pc, and both works properly, but even I connect both it seems they do not sum up, it gets the iPhone speed, but looks like wired is not used

funny thing (or not) ipconfig shows the two Ethernets on same network (172.20.10.9 & ...2) and same gateway for both 172.20.10.1

can something be done?

Comment: No, network adapters do not "sum up".

Comment: but SO has two networks over to which send packages, 
is not using both at the same time?, or could d it?

Comment: I agree with harrymc

Comment: Even if you got it wirking, I dont see how it can get half the resource on one and half on another. It will use one or other.

Comment: I mean, speed is limited by the bandwith of the connection. If some connection goes by one connection, another by the other one, total available speed for the whole computer, should be the sum of both, isnt it?

Comment: With basic capable hardware you can "load balance" between two connections, meaning that when one goes down connection can be switched. It would require more capable hardware and probably at both ends in order to route traffic simultaneously across both links to "sum up" the connections, adding their speeds.

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of one I answered a few days ago: https://superuser.com/questions/1807124/bridging-wifi-and-lan-in-windows-10/1807279#1807279